# How do i check a javascript map contains keys which are in array?

Tags: javascript

Let's say that I have a map with keys : 1,2,3,4,5

and let's say I have an array which contains : [2,3,4]

what I am trying to do is iterate through map and remove keys 2,3,4

some final map will have 1,5 keys and their values

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also specify what you have already tried ? If you haven't tried anything yet, please do start and then ask a question when you are stuck. Please provide some code. Please also take a moment to read [how-to-ask on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to check, you can directly delete. Say `arr` is your map then do

```
var keysToRemove = [2,3,4];
keysToRemove.forEach( el => delete arr[el] )
```

Comment: Nice and simple :)

Comment: @nikhil thanks! updated to even shorter! :)

Comment: hi for some reason its not working ? code:http://prntscr.com/iinnip console:http://prntscr.com/iinnoo

Comment: @lastp4 please post your map as well.

Comment: what about deleting keys which are not equal to 2,3,4 i mean remove 1 and 5 so 2,3,4 will left http://prntscr.com/iinqo0         http://prntscr.com/iinqvt

Comment: In your question you have said `what i am trying to do is iterate through map and remove keys 2,3,4`

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` and `delete`

```
var map = {
    "1": "1",
    "2": "1",
    "3": "1",
    "4": "1",
    "5": "1"
};
var arr = [2,3,4];
arr.forEach( s => delete map[s] );
```

`map` is now

> {1: "1", 5: "1"}

Comment: This answer is already kinda there ;)

Comment: Yes, just saw that. In my defense, I had already written it before your edit :)